# Deleting records based on a group by in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-delete

I'm having trouble coming up with a query which is going to allow me to keep only the most recent order from a user (maybe a better way to say this is delete all old orders):

```
CREATE TABLE orders(id integer, created_at datetime, user_id integer, label nvarchar(25));

INSERT INTO orders values(1, now(), 1, 'FRED FIRST');

INSERT INTO orders values(2, DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 'FRED SECOND');

INSERT INTO orders values(3, DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), 1, 'FRED THIRD');

INSERT INTO orders values(4, DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 3, 'BARNEY FIRST');

SELECT * FROM orders;

'1','2014-03-07 08:39:36','1','FRED FIRST'
'2','2014-03-08 08:39:36','1','FRED SECOND'
'3','2014-03-09 08:39:36','1','FRED THIRD'
'4','2014-03-08 08:39:36','3','BARNEY FIRST'
```

I would like to run a query which would leave me with FRED's THIRD order and BARNEY's FIRST order. FRED FIRST and FRED SECOND should be deleted because they are not the latest order from FRED.

Any thoughts about how I might be able to do this with a single query?

EDIT: After posting this, I found something that works (it does what I'm looking to do)-- but it seems a bit messy:

```
DELETE  old_orders
FROM orders old_orders
left outer join(
SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at, user_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY user_id) new_orders
ON new_orders.user_id = old_orders.user_id and new_orders.created_at = old_orders.created_at
WHERE new_orders.user_id is null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested query, like this:

```
DELETE FROM orders
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    select id from orders o JOIN (
      select user_id, max(created_at) t from orders group by user_id
    ) o1 ON o.user_id = o1.user_id AND o.created_at = o1.t
  ) AS tmp
)
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d913/1

Comment: Thanks much-- any ideas how that compares to the solution I came up with? see my Edit...

Comment: @ek_ny you are welcome. Both queries are same at the inner most part, where MAX is used and the result is joined with original table to get id of the MAX row. In the outer part, I have used NOT IN whereas you have used LEFT JOIN. If you are asking about performance then I can't answer that. Better to execute the EXPLAIN statement for both queries and read the output.

Answer (score 0):

One way you might achieve this is to set a flag for the row indicating that it is the most recent order. So when a new order is placed you would clear the flag on other orders for that customer and set the flag for the row that your inserting. Then your DELETE query could just delete all orders that don't have that flag set.